# @angular/fire manipulate response observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire

I am working with @angular/fire 9 in compatibility mode using the real time database.  While I am returning the observable from my service into my controller, and this works fine, I am having trouble manipulating data being returned.

For instance, my service needs to get all the records from a table, and perform some math on each record. To get the straight forward list, then use the async() pipe in my Angular controller, I use a service method like:

```
public GetTransactionDetails(TransactionNo: string): Observable<Array<TransactionItemDetails>> {
    const Location: string = `TransDetail/${TransactionNo}`;
    const ItemListing$ = this.AngularFireDB_.list<TransactionItemDetails>(Location, ref => ref.orderByChild('item_code')).valueChanges();
    return ItemListing$;
}
```

This works to get my list of detail, with all the information I have in the table in @angular/fire.  However, I am not storing the Total Price, and want to calculate that by multiplying the Quantity * Unit Price.  I cannot seem to get a map function to work in this case.

```
public GetTransactionDetails(TransactionNo: string): Observable<Array<TransItemDetail>> {
    const Location: string = `TransDetail/${TransactionNo}`;
    const ItemListing$ = this.AngularFireDB_.list<TransItemDetail>(Location, ref => ref.orderByChild('item_code')).valueChanges().pipe( map(AllItems: Array<TransItemDetail>) => {
        // My understanding is this is all the data, so I need to loop again through this.
        AllItems.map( (OneItem: TransItemDetail) => {
            OneItem.ItemTotal = OneItem.Quantity * OneItem.UnitPrice;
        });
    });
    return ItemListing$;
}
```

However, I get compile errors in this format.

```
Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<TransItemDetail[]>'.
```

Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'TransItemDetail[]'.ts(2322)

If I then add the definition to the pipe, the error changes to:

```
pipe<Array<TransItemDetail>>( map(AllItems: Array<TransItemDetail>) => {

Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<TransItemDetail[], void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<TransItemDetail[], TransItemDetail[]>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'TransItemDetail[]'.ts(2345)
```

I do not know how to move past this to get my results.

Comment: you do not `return` your `AllItems.map(...)`.  This is why TS shows you error mentioning `Observable<void>`, because you don't return anything from your map function.

Comment: Thanks.  Just managed to refactor that myself and see that is the case.  If you want to move that to an answer, I can accept it.